# Nuxt generate static website using JSON sever

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to generate a static website using nuxt with Json server [Fake api server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). I am just trying to pre-poplulate the static site with data from the json server using npm run generate. Thanks for all help!

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  async asyncData() {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/gallery')
    return { gallery: data }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <section class="gallery-grid">
    <nuxt-link
      v-for="i in gallery"
      :key="i.id"
      :to="'/'+i.id">
      <img
        :src="['gallery/'] + i.src + ['.jpg']"
        :alt="i.title">
    </nuxt-link>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what problem you're having, specifically.   Are you not getting the data?  Is the data in an unexpected format?  Are there any error messages?  What's your stack?  Is this just for local use?